# Which are the possible ways to retrain a model made in IBM Watson Knowledge Studio?

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

I am working on a knowledge based chatbot creation on ibm watson and I have trained my custom model on ibm watson knowledge studio for agricultural database. Now if someone asked about any information that is not available in our dataset then how can we retrained that model/improve the model with that new data ?

I am using knowledge graph to retrieve the information. Knowledge graph is made in Neo4J.

If any new data comes or admin wants to retrain the model with new data than the model should retrained without going to knowledge studio like rasa is ibm watson assistant provides feedback system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Watson Knowledge Studio does not support online training to retrain the existing model with new data. To adapt to new data, you need to train a brand new model with both the new data and the existing data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is there any other technology/platform that supports retraining for chatbot improvements. And also supporting knowledge graph.